# jquery each on ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using `each()` on the result of my AJAX request, my code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function() {
        str = [];
        $i = 0;
        $(".div_class").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'my_url',
                cache: false,
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.result); // alert 1
                    str.push({$i : data.result});
                }
            });
            $i++;
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(str)); // alert 2
    }
</script>
```

I am getting result in `alert(data.result)`.

The problem is the alert 2 `alert(JSON.stringify(str));` is appearing first and with an empty value.

Does any one know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the AJAX request is *asynchronous*. This means script execution continues while waiting for the return value - which is why you see `alert 2` before `alert 1`.

When working with async methods, ***all*** code which depends on the request should be placed in the callback function. In other words, `alert 2` has to be placed *inside* the `success` handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ajax call is an async one, the statement  `alert(JSON.stringify(str));` will be executed right after the ajax call and it will not wait for the request to be finished. If you want to stringify it, then do it in `success` or `done` methods

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the asynchronous nature of ajax requests

You can use $.when()

```
function my_function() {
    var requests = [];
    var str = [];
    $(".div_class").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var req = $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'my_url',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.result); // alert 1
                str.push({
                    $i: data.result
                });
            }
        });
        requests.push(req);
    });

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify(str)); // alert 2
    })
}
```

---

If you want to maintian the order of items then you can

```
function my_function() {
    var requests = $(".div_class").map(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'my_url',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.result); // alert 1
            }
        });
    }).get();

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
        var str = $.map(arguments, function (arr) {
            return arr[0].result;
        })
        alert(JSON.stringify(str)); // alert 2
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/11t2ah9f/)